# Move sqlite database in IsolatedStorage

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

I have a sqlite database declared in the root of my project (belongside MainPage.xaml etc.).

How can i place this database in IsolatedStorage? I can't seem to open the database now so i think it might be because it's not in Isolated Storage. How can i move it?

Comment: please show some source code...

Comment: @BadescuAlexandru have you tried the SQLite to SQLCE migration tool?
http://sqlite2ce.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code I used:

```
IsolatedStorageFile isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

if (!isf.FileExists("my.db"))
{
    StreamResourceInfo sri = App.GetResourceStream(new Uri("my.db", UriKind.Relative));

    IsolatedStorageFileStream isfs = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("my.db", FileMode.Create, IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication());

    long FileLength = (long)sri.Stream.Length;
    byte[] byteInput = new byte[FileLength];
    sri.Stream.Read(byteInput, 0, byteInput.Length);
    isfs.Write(byteInput, 0, byteInput.Length);

    sri.Stream.Close();
    isfs.Close();
}
```

If I remember correctly, you have to mark your DB as Content/Copy Always.

Comment: i had a weird problem integrating, still didn't figure things out. i tried to integrate http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/silverlight/Windows-Phone-7-Native-Database-Programming-via-Sqlite-Client-for-Windows-Phone.aspx in my project but it didn't work at all. Since i'm starting my app from scratch, i'm going to use the sample app. Thanks for the help, your method is the correct one, my project just had a bug somewhere..

Comment: @BadescuAlexandru Since you are starting your app from scratch, forget SQLite and use the database support built into Mango - it's just more straightforward.

Comment: i am starting the app from scratch, but the database is given, and it's sqlite. Thanks for the tip, i would have tried the mango db alternative first hand.